# Rails/Phusion Passenger listing only files

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, passenger

After installing phusion passenger and deploying my rails application, when I go to [a link] http://servername.example.com/app, I am seeing only the files listed under my app/public directory. I made sure that "app" is pointing to "app/public" directory and the phusion passenger settings right as per the user doc.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit was SELinux not allowing apache to run phusion passenger. I found the answer here - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phusion-passenger/qaVUIq2HceE.

Here is how I fixed it:

```
[root@server conf]# getenforce
Enforcing
[root@server conf]# echo 0 > /selinux/enforce
[root@server conf]# getenforce
Permissive
[root@server conf]# service httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
[root@server conf]# passenger-status
----------- General information -----------
max      = 6
count    = 0
active   = 0
inactive = 0
Waiting on global queue: 0

----------- Application groups -----------
[root@server conf]#
```

Now, when I go to my app URL, it works fine.